# MacBook Pro with external GPU force some apps to use internal gpu?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, macbook, macbook-pro

Hello I have a MacBook Pro with a external GPU hooked up. I'm using the external GPU for deep learning. When I start the deep learning the external GPU is pegged 100% usage. However the internal gpu is idle. The problem is when I open any program it seems to want to run on the external gpu. For example opening safari it will try to render using the external GPU. Making a unusable machine. If I could force safari to use the internal gpu and monitor then I could keep working on other stuff while the external gpu is running my deep learning software. Does anyone know of a script or something to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If I don't have my external monitor hooked up then plug in the e-gpu it will not affect performance of my GUI while training.